# multiple values with preceding-sibling

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

can i get both multiple values with preceding-sibling function

**preceding-sibling::td="半場角球" and "角球"**

HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td width="295" align="right" class="bg2">
        <div class="barBg2">
            <div class="info" style="width:82%;"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50" align="center" class="bg2">14</td>
    <td width="110" align="center" class="bg4">角球</td>
    <td width="50" align="center" class="bg2">3</td>
    <td width="295" align="left" class="bg2">
        <div class="barBg">
            <div class="info" style="width:18%;"></div>
        </div></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td width="295" align="right" class="bg1">
        <div class="barBg2">
            <div class="info" style="width:79%;"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">11</td>
    <td width="110" align="center" class="bg3">半場角球</td>
    <td width="50" align="center" class="bg1">3</td>
    <td width="295" align="left" class="bg1">
        <div class="barBg">
            <div class="info" style="width:21%;"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Python code

```
texts = [td.text for td in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//td[(preceding-sibling::td="半場角球" and "角球") and not(div)]')]
```

Expected Output

```
3 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
//td[(preceding-sibling::td="半場角球" or preceding-sibling::td="角球") and not(div)]
```